# Is there a python equivalent to Laravel 4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, laravel

Laravel 4 enables me to develop both small scale and enterprise scale app's easily and efficiently, and its modular concepts allow me to extend it core, build custom reusable packages, and easily follow TDD practices.

I have been diving into the wonderful world of python (v3) and wondered what the equivalent web framework would be in the python community? A framework that follows some of the same core concepts built into Laravel 4 such as MVC design pattern, easy testing, modular design, packages etc.

Comment: Any constructive feedback from the down voters would be helpful.

Comment: +1 just because of the downvotes. It's an interesting question

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes. [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/about) is what you are looking for. It's written from the ground up to be based in common Python libraries and components, and you can swap out pieces for other pieces as you wish. Python as a language is geared for TDD, and Pyramid takes advantage of that. You can push your own libraries, if they are abstract enough, out to PyPi for yourself, if you wish, but you can of course just keep them within your own projects too.

There are other Python frameworks, but if you're looking for modular and extensible, without a whole lot of framework interference in your working style preference, Pyramid is the way to go.

P.S. this question is better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ah, a downvote, even though Pyramid meets every requirement specified in the question. Well done.

Comment: Indeed, no idea why. Equalized now :)

Comment: Thanks bicycle. I suppose I could expand my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Pyramid looks nice at first glance of their website and documentation. I'll check it out and give it whirl.

Comment: Is their anyway to port a question over to programmers.stackexchange.com, should I recreate the question over their or leave it here as is?

Comment: I don't know of a way to transfer questions, so either see if it gets closed and redirected automatically to programmers, or just repost over there too. Of course, my answer is the One True Answer anyway, so  no need to ask again, right? :)

Answer (score 8):

Python also has a web framework called [Masonite](https://github.com/MasoniteFramework/masonite/) which is a lot like Laravel. Heavily inspired by Laravel and a lot of Laravel developers can pick it up really easily.

Also has an ORM called Masonite ORM which is heavily inspired by eloquent

Answer (score 4):

You can look at the framework I'm currently building, namely [glim](http://github.com/aacanakin/glim). There exists inspiration from play framework & laravel in it. You can get more information from the [docs](http://glim.readme.io) page.

It also has an extension system where developers can integrate to it. 
You can look at the [extensions](http://github.com/aacanakin/glim-extensions) I have built;